# Detecting WiFi and other settings on Android phones

Tags: android, bluetooth, settings, global

I'm trying to test whether a phone has bluetooth, WiFi, adb, passcode and log enabled. I'm having errors with the `getInt()` method, and I think it has to do with the `cr` variable. I'm fairly new to this type of android programming.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.quotes_list);
    mListView.setAdapter(new QuoteAdapter(this));

    //determine if phone uses lock pattern
    ContentResolver cr = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
    int lockPatternEnable;

    lockPatternEnable = Settings.Secure.getInt(cr, Settings.Secure.LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED, 0);

    if (lockPatternEnable==0)
    {
        //lock pattern enabled
        lockPatternEnableBool = true;
    }
    if (lockPatternEnable==1)
    {
        //lock pattern disabled
        lockPatternEnableBool = false;
    }

    //determine if adb is enabled
    adb=Settings.Global.getInt(cr, Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED, 0);


    //determine if bluetooth is enabled
    bluetooth=Settings.Global.getInt(cr, Settings.Global.BLUETOOTH_ON, 0);

    //determine if wifi is enabled
    wifi=Settings.Global.getInt(cr, Settings.Global.WIFI_ON, 0);

}// end of onCreate method
```